# Accord.net Bag of visual words

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net

I just created, trained and saved my bag of visual word file,
but some how i am not able to load it,
here is my sample code:

```
var bow1 = Serializer.Load<BagOfVisualWords>(ktt + @"\bow_1992.bin");
```

any help please? thanks

here is the error message i get:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Object must implement IConvertible.'

Note: I use C#.Net

Comment: Vague verbal descriptions like "*somehow I am not able to read it*" are not very useful for possible respondents. Please post the exact error trace (not in the comments, edit & update your post).

Comment: Ok, please have a look it again, thanks for your comment